# In App Notification and Background Notification

Tags: android, swift, flutter, kotlin, flutter-local-notification

In my Flutter app I am using Local Scheduled Notification which is send to user when it is scheduled( It is Working Fine).

When Application is running than it should show in as In App Notification and If App is in Background than it should send Actual Notification.

I have successfully implemented in Native Ios app (AppDelegate.swift) file here is the code :

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void
    ) {
        // Check if the app is in the foreground
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {

            let title = notification.request.content.title
            let body = notification.request.content.body
            showAlert(title: title, body: body)
            completionHandler([])
        } else {
            completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
        }
    }

    private func showAlert(title: String, body: String) {
        // Show alert dialog
        let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: title,
            message: body,
            preferredStyle: .alert
        )
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

- What I want i want to perform same functionality in my Android (Kotlin) app.
- When Android app is Running than it should show In app Notification and if App is closed or App is in background than show actual scheduled notification.